# Odoo 10 - product qty in a location shown in move_lines of internal stock transfer

Tags: odoo-10

It is for Odoo v10

When create a move within Inventory > Internal transfer, the default move_lines shows:

Product, Qty, Status

I want to add the product qty of the location_zone (stock). Is it possible? I wonder what my approach should be.

[image]

Comment: I have to clarify my question. I want to display how many qty of the product exists in the source location_zone while I am going to create an internal transfer in move_lines.

Comment: I want to show "Qty in Stock" of the Source Location behind the Product column in the move_lines.

Comment: i have no idea to add a column behind a product to show the qty in the source location.

Answer (score 0):

Login as admin and in the warehouse settings activate multiple warehouses and locations. Then in Internal transfer you will be able to specify the location also.

Comment: A few screenshots would be very helpful.

Comment: I have added a screen for better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

> total_availability =
>   self.env['stock.quant']._get_available_quantity(self.product_id,
>   self.location_id)

for more information Goto stock-->addons\stock\models\stock_move.py
Method :

```
>  def _compute_product_availability(self):
```